# How to crop JPG and PNG with transparent background on JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, png, crop, jcrop

I'm using a plugin named "jcrop", it's pretty nice, you can see it here:

http://howhack.com/crop/demos/crop2.php

The issue is this plugin do not support png with transparent backgrounds.

Is there a similar script/plugin in javascript / jQuery that supports png with transparent backgrounds?

I need this rectangle thing with aspect ratio 16:9 and a final image always 640x360, that's why I'm trying to use this "jcrop".

Comment: Because the aspect ratio must be fixed to 16:9 and you don't know which part of the image the user want to show, and even doing it like you say the transparent background will not be there :/

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming the plugin does the image editing on the server via PHP? If so, you need to make a few special calls to preserve alpha transparency in PNG images:

```
$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];
$w = $_GET["w"];
$h = $_GET["h"];

// Load the original image.
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img_path);
imagealphablending($img, true);

// Create a blank canvas for the cropped image.
$img_cropped = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagesavealpha($img_cropped, true);
imagealphablending($img_cropped, false);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img_cropped, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($img_cropped, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Crop the image and store the data on the blank canvas.
imagecopyresampled($img_cropped, $img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, $w, $h); // or imagecopy()

// Save the image.
imagepng($img_cropped, "image_cropped.png", 2);

// Free memory.
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($img_cropped);
```

This is touched on a few times in the discussion for PHP's imagecopyresampled() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can do the with canvas so much easier and if you want to save it you just send the raw canvas data to the server via post?
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

But if you want to use this plugin, what I would suggest is that you look at your server's php configuration. A lot of servers still only support jpeg and gif as part of their default php configurations. If you want to check this make a php file with this code in it:

phpinfo();

?>

and then upload and view it on your server. you should look for "libpng" on the page:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.requirements.php

Comment: Thanks Alex, but that's not what I need, I need precision, the user must be able to choose exactly which part of the image, then the image will be saved as a new file. If I could use a canvas I would not being here asking how to do this. Anyway I will check the phpinfo.

Comment: @NerdsTalk: Alex is correct, this can be done with a canvas element. Depending on where your source data is stored (either on the server, or locally on the user's computer), you may or may not want to do it though. You can feed the canvas image to the browser locally, after manipulating it, so that it can be saved. If you need to archive the cropped image on your server, you should probably stick with PHP.